# Use multiprocessings 'Pool' together with 'RawArray'

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

Whenever I try to use shared memory with pythons 'multiprocessing' module to fill a huge array in parallel I use something like:

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, RawArray

def tf(x, arr):
    arr = np.reshape( np.frombuffer( arr, dtype=np.float32 ), -1 ).reshape((10, 10, 10))
    arr[x] = np.random.random((10, 10))
    
mpa = RawArray('f', 1000)
ncpu = 4

procs = []
for i in range(10):
    procs.append(Process(target=tf, args=(i, mpa)))
    procs[-1].start()                                    
    if len(procs) == ncpu:
        procs[0].join()
        procs.pop(0)

for p in procs:
    p.join()
   
arr = np.reshape( np.frombuffer( mpa, dtype=np.uint32 ), -1).reshape((10, 10, 10))
```

to ensure that only as many processes are active as I have cpus. If I try to use 'Pool' and 'apply_async' the array is not altered for some reason. So I wonder if it is possible to either use 'Pool' or any other intended way to manage the amount of active processes.

The above code is working but is not the most efficient since I only if the process I added first is finished to decide if I should add another process.

Comment: It would be best if you showed the version that doesn't work, so we can correct you...

Comment: The code works as intended, I'm just curious how I should do it properly since my method feels a bit hacked.

Comment: I see the same behavior. Utilizing a pool leaves the arr with zeros. What baffles me is how come the `Process` version even works... The function doesn't seem to alter the array at all...

Comment: I use shared memory with 'RawArray' and the numpy-routine is just a wrapper for the memory, so theoretically it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was not answered yet, I'll share a simple `Pool` replacement I designed for this kind of problem.

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, RawArray
from time import sleep

class Simple_Pool:
    def __init__(self, ncpu, target):
        self.ncpu = ncpu
        self.target = target
        self.params = []

    def add_process(self, parameters):
        self.params.append(parameters)

    def run_processes(self, wait_time=1e-3):
        procs = []
        for params in self.params:
            procs.append(Process(target=self.target, args=params))
            procs[-1].start()
            if len(procs) == self.ncpu:
                wait = True
                while wait:
                    for p, proc in enumerate(procs):
                        if not proc.is_alive():
                            proc.join()
                            procs.pop(p)
                            wait = False
                            break
                    # Adjust sleep time to your needs
                    sleep(wait_time)

        for p in procs:
            p.join()

def do_work(i, j, arr, pixel):
    print(f'Working on pixel ({i}, {j}), waiting {pixel:.3f} seconds')
    sleep(pixel)
    # get numpy array from the shared memory
    arr = np.frombuffer(arr, dtype=np.float32).reshape((M, N, 3))

    # do some work, here we just assign the pixel value times 0, 1 and 2
    arr[i, j] = np.arange(3) * pixel


M, N = 10, 5

# load image from file, here we just use a random array
image = np.random.random((M, N))

# create shared memory for the parameters
parameters = RawArray('f', M * N * 3)
ncpu = 4

P = Simple_Pool(ncpu, do_work)

for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        P.add_process((i, j, parameters, image[i, j]))

# wait_time is the time between checking if any process has finished
P.run_processes(wait_time=1e-3)

# # get numpy array from the shared memory
parameters = np.frombuffer(parameters, dtype=np.float32).reshape((M, N, 3))
```